# How do I get local image using separate data.jsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I tried it both ways but it didn't work!

```
const Data = [
    {
        image: ('./cake.png'),
        title:"candy", 
        text:"Orange Candy", 
        ingred :"abc, xyx", 
        price:"$5"
    },
    {
        image:"../assets/images/cake.png",
        title:"cake", 
        text:"Cake", 
        ingred :"pqr, aaa", 
        price:"$10"
    }

];
export default Data;
```

[image: data.jsx showing in the below image]

Comment: how you import it?

Answer (score 0):

docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

usage:

```
    import React, {FC} from 'react';
    import {Image, SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react-native';

    const data = {
      image: require('./src/assets/random-picture.png'),
      text: 'lala random text',
    };

    const App: FC = () => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Image source={data.image} />

          <Text>{data.text}</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

alternative:

create `types.d.ts` in root directory
add

```
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.svg';
```

save

use imports:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {Image, SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react-native';
import RandomImage from './src/assets/random-picture.png';

const data = {
  image: RandomImage,
  text: 'lala random text',
};

const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Image source={data.image} />

      <Text>{data.text}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: working on React js website, How do I get multiple data on a single component card?

Comment: question is too vague.

Comment: how do I get local images from data.jsx file to my app component as React cards!!